# Generic extension on Numeric protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to extend Swift's Numeric protocol with a method that divides one `Numeric` type by another of the same type like this:

```
extension Numeric {
  func percentage<T>(of: T) -> T where T.Type == Self.Type {
    return self / of
  }
}
```

But I get the error

> Same-type requirement makes generic parameters 'T' and 'Self' equivalent

It works when it's not a protocol extension, but I'd love to know if it's possible to do it as an extension and what this error means.

This works:

```
func percentage<T: Numeric>(n1: T, n2: T) -> T {
  return n1 / n2
}
let d = x(n1: 2.0, n2: 3.0)
```

Comment: I wonder why it is not working , It should be fine raising  bug to swift https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11041

Comment: `func percentage()` does *not* compile.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: Did you check that your “However this is working fine” code in the bug report compiles? It does not compile for me.

Comment: @MartinR nope, I have added  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56800173/4601900 this code . not the code in question

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: Well, you should verify if it compiles, before making that claim in the bug report :)

Comment: Btw, this [has been discussed](https://forums.swift.org/t/division-related-numeric-extensions/9563) in the Swift forum.

Comment: The protocol hierarchy can be found here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md#proposed-solution.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for `T`.

```
extension Numeric {
    func percentage<Self>(of whole: Self) -> Self {
        return self / whole
    }
}
```

Comment: @Honey Yeah, I'm not sure why the compiler doesn't just emit a warning and allow it

Comment: The compiler is merely throwing an error, because `T.Type == Self.Type` isn't desirable. Otherwise syntactically it's not wrong. Right?

Comment: @Honey Yeah, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be allowed

Comment: This does not compile, because `Numeric` does not define a division operator. – And why use `<Self>` as a generic placeholder? That would shadow `Numeric.Self`.

Comment: @MartinR  **This does not compile, because Numeric does not define a division operator** However there is * (multiply ) operator in numeric. but with generic  it is also not working

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: That is because of the wrong type placeholder `<Self>` that I mentioned above. `func multiple(of whole: Self) -> Self { return self * whole }` does compile.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya That's a problem that exists with your free function, too. I've only solved the "generic" issue, but `Numeric` is still the wrong protocol for the job here. `FloatingPoint` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Actually @Alexander's answer isn't working for me, since `Numeric` protocol type does not support division. `Numeric` percentage value also has limited use when applied to an integer division.

You can overcome these issues by limiting it to the `FloatingPoint` protocol instead. Also bear in mind this isn't a percentage function per se - multiply by 100 to get that, i.e.:

```
extension FloatingPoint 
{
  func percentage(of whole: Self) -> Self
  {
    return (self / whole) * 100
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that has always been the case, all versions (although I'd accept someone telling me otherwise) - [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric).